# AWS CloudFront Custom domain name with HTTPS not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

1.I have a domain purchased through godaddy. I have set custom DNS and added 4 name servers generated by the hosted zone in AWS Route 53. DNS lookup through whois.net shows the correct values.

2.In Route 53, I have added an A record to the Alias Target xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net. So the traffic hits Route 53 and goes to CloudFront.

3.In CloudFront, I have one distribution. As Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs), I have the following values:
 *.domain.com / www.domain.com / domain.com
Under origins, I have one record with the following Origin Domain Name:
domain.com.s3-website.az-name-1.amazonaws.com

4.I am hosting website in an S3 bucket. All HTTP requests are set to redirect to HTTPS.

5.Lastly, I have created (US East (N. Virginia) region) and verified a single certificate for the following domain names: domain.com, www.domain.com, *.domain.com
I have read some answers that I should just wait and the custom SSL certificate option will become enabled. It's been more than day now, however, and there is no sign of that happening.

My website works in http mode, but not in https url. Any solution ...Please help...
PS. I am new to aws, please help me...

Comment: you have set All HTTP requests are set to redirect to HTTPS.hence it will accept only http mode, if you want it to work for https, then allow https as well in your cloud front configuration.

Comment: @UsmanAzhar that doesn't make sense.  All HTTP requests redirect to HTTPS means HTTPS is accepted and HTTP gets redirected.

Answer (score 14):

HTTPS settings was working perfectly as cloudfront url was working as expected so I realized it was just a DNS issue. All it took was an TYPE A record pointing to it.

Solution :
Add/edit proper "TYPE A" record with "Alias Target" as a cloudfront url.

Credit : [Setup AWS S3 static website hosting using SSL (ACM)](https://medium.com/@robmuh/really-appreciate-this-write-up-3375a69fc479)

Comment: in the original question, you have already added A record in step 2, what was changed?

Answer (score 4):

For me the solution was very simple... I failed to add "Alternate Domain Name", once I did everything clicked.

Answer (score 3):

Can you confirm whether you have used ACM to generate the SSL certificate? Or you are using SSL certificate from other vendors?

**STEP 1:**
If you have generated the SSL Certificate from ACM, please make sure you did that with US East (N. Virginia) region. Because, CloudFront being an AWS service which is not tied to any specific region, it will use the certificates from US East region only.

**STEP 2:**
 1. Use the "Request or Import a certificate" option in CloudFront
 2. Select the certificate which you generated
 3. Complete the setup and try

If everything else is setup fine, you should be able to access the contents with HTTPS after the above step.

Let me know in case it didn't work

Comment: hey I am having some strange issue...https will work for sometime...it was working yesterday night (Indian time) but not today morning..any setting I have to do?

Comment: I am getting this error message on screen :

This site can’t be reached

Domain.com took too long to respond.

Try:

Checking the connection

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Http is working fine.. Yesterday night https was working fine as expected..

Comment: Is your port 443 still open to internet? Try telnet to port 443 and check if its connecting

Comment: Yes 443 working..It is not accessible from mobile data also...yesterday it was working..

Comment: Now my website working with https site ..dont know what is the issue..confused now..even though telnet domain 443 not happening from my home wifi...:-/

Comment: Is it still having issues or stabilized?

Comment: That sounds strange. Is there any specific pattern for the timing when the HTTPS is not working? Something like morning hours/evening hours or something like that? OR is it like HTTPs is not working for some requests while working for some other requests always?

Comment: Can you share the url which you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

> Also check that AWS Route 53 Registered Domain Name Servers match the AWS Route 53 Hosted Zones /  Record Type "NS" "Value/Route traffic to" servers.

If they do not match, which has happened to me several times during custom domain cloudfront setup, then copy the Hosted Zones /  Record Type "NS" "Value/Route traffic to" servers over to the Registered Domain Name Servers in the Route 53 tab.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else coming across this issue, the button was greyed out for me also and YES, I had requested the ACM cert in us-east-1.

The fix was to try in the Edge browser instead of Chrome.